# I change CSS using Javascript, and the transition is instantaneous instead of taking several seconds

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I have a dropdown navigation menu which I want to change the CSS styling on (specifically the opacity of the navigation links such that they fade in), and the styles are properly changed, except that there is no transition between the style values.

I am trying to use a transition on the change in opacity to make the navigation links fade into view once the dropdown menu is behind them.

```js
      var notViewingMenu = true;
      var button = document.getElementById("navList");
      var view = document.getElementById("navbarLinkList");
      var dropMenu = document.getElementById("navbarLinks");
      var navPath = document.getElementById("navListPath");
      var links = document.getElementsByClassName("navLink");

      button.addEventListener('click', function(){
        if (notViewingMenu) {
          links[0].style.opacity = "1.0";
          links[1].style.opacity = "1.0";
          links[2].style.opacity = "1.0";
          links[3].style.opacity = "1.0";
          view.style.display = "block";
          navPath.style.fill = "D90000";
          dropMenu.style.height = "100vh";
          notViewingMenu = false;
        } else {
          links[0].style.opacity = "0.0";
          links[1].style.opacity = "0.0";
          links[2].style.opacity = "0.0";
          links[3].style.opacity = "0.0";
          view.style.display = "none";
          navPath.style.fill = "#000000";
          dropMenu.style.height = "0vh";
          notViewingMenu = true;
        }
      })
```

```css
      #navbarLinkList {
        padding-top: 44px;
        list-style: none;
        display: none;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        z-index: 44;
      }

      #navbarLinks {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 0vh;
        width: 100vw;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.9);
        list-style: none;
        position: absolute;
        float: left;
        z-index: -10;
        transition: height 1s;
        -o-transition: height 1s;
        -moz-transition: height 1s;
        -webkit-transition: height 1s;
      }

      .navLink {
        opacity: 0.0;
        position: relative;
        font-size: 7vw;
        font-family: 'helvetica';
        list-style: none;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        transition: opacity 2s;
        -o-transition: opacity 2s;
        -moz-transition: opacity 2s;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 2s;
      }
```

```html
    <navbar>
      <svg id="navList">
        <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
          <path id="navListPath" d="M0,0 L19,0 L19,2 L0,2 L0,0 Z M0,7 L19,7 L19,9 L0,9 L0,7 Z M0,14 L19,14 L19,16 L0,16 L0,14 Z" id="Combined-Shape" fill="#000000"></path>
        </g>
      </svg>
      <nav id="navbarLinks">
       <ul id="navbarLinkList">
          <li><a class="navLink" href="../index.html">home</a></li>
          <li><a class="navLink" href="index.html">team</a></li>
          <li><a class="navLink" href="index.html">portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a class="navLink" href="index.html">submission</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </navbar>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is actually with #navbarLinkList: you're transitioning it between display:block and display:none, which is instantly hiding/showing the links. The display attribute cannot be animated, so you should not have it change as part of an animation. The fading works if I leave it always set to display:block.

```js
      var notViewingMenu = true;
      var button = document.getElementById("navList");
      var view = document.getElementById("navbarLinkList");
      var dropMenu = document.getElementById("navbarLinks");
      var navPath = document.getElementById("navListPath");
      var links = document.getElementsByClassName("navLink");

      button.addEventListener('click', function(){
        if (notViewingMenu) {
          links[0].style.opacity = "1.0";
          links[1].style.opacity = "1.0";
          links[2].style.opacity = "1.0";
          links[3].style.opacity = "1.0";
          //view.style.display = "block";
          navPath.style.fill = "D90000";
          dropMenu.style.height = "100vh";
          notViewingMenu = false;
        } else {
          links[0].style.opacity = "0.0";
          links[1].style.opacity = "0.0";
          links[2].style.opacity = "0.0";
          links[3].style.opacity = "0.0";
          //view.style.display = "none";
          navPath.style.fill = "#000000";
          dropMenu.style.height = "0vh";
          notViewingMenu = true;
        }
      })
```

```css
      #navbarLinkList {
        padding-top: 44px;
        list-style: none;
        display: block;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        z-index: 44;
      }

      #navbarLinks {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 0vh;
        width: 100vw;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.9);
        list-style: none;
        position: absolute;
        float: left;
        z-index: -10;
        transition: height 1s;
        -o-transition: height 1s;
        -moz-transition: height 1s;
        -webkit-transition: height 1s;
      }

      .navLink {
        opacity: 0.0;
        position: relative;
        font-size: 7vw;
        font-family: 'helvetica';
        list-style: none;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        transition: opacity 2s;
        -o-transition: opacity 2s;
        -moz-transition: opacity 2s;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 2s;
      }
```

```html
    <navbar>
      <svg id="navList">
        <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
          <path id="navListPath" d="M0,0 L19,0 L19,2 L0,2 L0,0 Z M0,7 L19,7 L19,9 L0,9 L0,7 Z M0,14 L19,14 L19,16 L0,16 L0,14 Z" id="Combined-Shape" fill="#000000"></path>
        </g>
      </svg>
      <nav id="navbarLinks">
       <ul id="navbarLinkList">
          <li><a class="navLink" href="../index.html">home</a></li>
          <li><a class="navLink" href="index.html">team</a></li>
          <li><a class="navLink" href="index.html">portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a class="navLink" href="index.html">submission</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </navbar>
```